# Documentum to SVN migration

Tags: svn, migration, documentum

Is there a tool/ any programmatic way to migrate documentum content into SVN with revision history?

Comment: What is "documentum content"? User attachments? Docbase objects? or somethink else?

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool for this AFAIK, and I'd be surprised if there were. Document management and version control are just conceptually really different. Document management focuses on the storage of content (files) along with its meta-data. It doesn't care much about what's inside those files. And with version control systems it's all about this.

I guess you could write a program that uses DFC/DFS to fetch the whole version tree of a document and check it into Subversion, oldest version first. I don't know where you would store your Documentum meta-data though. Also, I wouldn't know what to do if the Documentum document has a branched version tree.

Answer (score 0):

There is deep export utility on EMC dev network  which can be used to export everything from the folder to your local SVN folder .